# Which functions in $C_c(\Bbb R)$ can be approximated by a sequence of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis

Where $C_c(\Bbb R)$ is the space of compactly supported continuous functions and using the sup norm. By approximated I mean being able to find a sequence of polynomials that converges uniformly to the function.

Comment: Approximated in what sense? For which norm/topology?

Comment: Check out the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem?  It will help you.

Comment: @Charlie : Stone-Weierstrass Theorem works only on bounded intervals. Here it's $\Bbb R$ and is unbounded. The "problem" is that ever non constant polynomial has an infinite norm for $\|.\|\infty$,

Comment: I've edited it to clarify a bit

Comment: Just $0$: as Tryss wrote, if $g\in \Bbb R[x]\setminus \Bbb R$ and $f\in C_c(\Bbb R)$, then $\sup\limits_{x\in \Bbb R}\lvert f(x)-g(x)\rvert=+\infty$. So only constant polynomials can converge uniformly to compactly supported functions. Constants converge uniformly to constants, and the only compactyl supported constant function is $0$.

Comment: @Tryss you're right, of course.  I was thinking the author may settle for a piecewise defined function that restricts to a polynomial on each connected component of the support.